# How to add images to Actions on google carousel?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm in the process on making a actions on google project and I am wanting to add a carousel to the action.

I understand the code end of things of how to add it to your action, but I'm a bit confused on how you get the **links** for your images. So for example, I seen in googles tutorial for carousel they have this following code snippet (to get it started):

```
const IMG_URL_AOG = 'https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges' +
   '/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png';   

const IMG_URL_GOOGLE_ALLO = 'https://allo.google.com/images/allo-logo.png';

const IMG_URL_GOOGLE_HOME = 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com' +
'/Nu3a6F80WfixUqf_ec_vgXy_c0-0r4VLJRXjVFF_X_CIilEu8B9fT35qyTEj_PEsKw';

const IMG_URL_GOOGLE_PIXEL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/madebygoog/v1' 
+
'/Pixel/Pixel_ColorPicker/Pixel_Device_Angled_Black-720w.png';

const IMG_URL_MEDIA = 'http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive- 
media/album_art.jpg';

const MEDIA_SOURCE = 'http://storage.googleapis.com/automotive- 
media/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3';

  // Constants for selected item responses
```

And if you actually type these links in, you will get something like [this](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Nu3a6F80WfixUqf_ec_vgXy_c0-0r4VLJRXjVFF_X_CIilEu8B9fT35qyTEj_PEsKw) back. The last two are other media types, but same idea.

Could someone explain how getting the images/ image links works for carousel's with actions on google? Do you have to make a html page for that image or am I  just overthinking this and you can take an image link from online and it will work (given the right size of course). I might have missed something in the docs.

Thanks for the help or suggestions!

To maybe provide further context, I'm going off of this [doc](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#carousel)

Comment: You just need a link to the image & it will work in your carousel.

Comment: Okay so I could use this link lets say an it will work fine? :https://www.google.ca/search?q=google+images&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnvMrV8JDfAhWFw4MKHdb1CL0Q_AUIDigB&biw=1366&bih=657#imgrc=gMGgvzFmcAFgGM:

Comment: Use a specific link. Above is a search result. [This](https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1057899591708753921/PSpUS-Hp_400x400.jpg) for example should work fine

Comment: Moreover if you have a local image, you can upload it to Firebase Storage and use the URL you get for that image in your response.

Comment: I think I got it, thanks for the help!